# Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml, php-5.4

I have this error :Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in on line 195

and also this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in C:\wamp\

so my code in following  :

```
foreach ( $GetJobResult->JobReferences as $jobreference_index => $JobReferences ) {
            if (isset ( $GetJobResult->JobReferences )) {

                $xmlJobReference = simplexml_load_string ( $JobReferences );

                $JobReferencetitle = $xmlJobReference->xpath ( "//JobReference[Title ='N°  ANCIEN DOSSIER']/Reference" );


                var_dump($GetJobResult->JobReferences);

            }
        }
```

var_dump($GetJobResult->JobReferences);

```
object(stdClass)[149]
  public 'JobReference' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[150]
          public 'Type' => string 'STANDARD' (length=8)
          public 'Title' => string 'NÂ° cde client' (length=14)
          public 'Reference' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'ValueType' => string 'ALPHANUMERIC' (length=12)
          public 'ValueLength_Minimum' => int 0
          public 'ValueLength_Maximum' => int 20
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[151]
          public 'Type' => string 'STANDARD' (length=8)
          public 'Title' => string 'NÂ°  ANCIEN DOSSIER' (length=19)
          public 'Reference' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'ValueType' => string 'NUMERIC' (length=7)
          public 'ValueLength_Minimum' => int 0
          public 'ValueLength_Maximum' => int 6
```

Comment: Put `var_dump($GetJobResult->JobReferences);` into if . Show result

Comment: it is not an xml at all. You need foreach ($JobReferences as $tem) and find $item->Title == your_value. Then take $item->Reference

Comment: @splash58 i use simplexml with xpath

Comment: for this you need xml at least

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `var_dump` output, the objects you are looping over haven't actually been produced by SimpleXML - they are `stdClass` objects, which is PHP's notation for "objects with no class".

You can't simply give an object to `simplexml_load_string` (which, as its name suggests, and the Warning confirms, expects a *string* value) and then have all the methods of SimpleXML such as `->xpath()` magically available.

If this was in fact XML, you need to find where in the code is parsing it into this set of `stdClass` objects, and replace the current parser with SimpleXML. If it wasn't XML, you need to find some other method of finding the child nodes, rather than XPath.

Answer (score 0):

[simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) transforms string to [SimpleXmlElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). You are passing object. Thats the problem.